# Have Office 2010, need to compile VB.Net for 2007

Tags: vb.net, interop, ms-office

Running VS 2010 under Win7 64-bit, and have Office 2010 installed. The application I'm working on opens and searches Excel spreadsheets and needs to run under Vista 32-bit with Office 2007.

I've tried the suggestion found here - drop Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel v14 and add v12 - but running o2007pia.msi just tells me I have to install Office 2007. I don't have Office 2007 available to me, and I can't install anything on the machines running Office 2007.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: You are possibly not looking ahead at what's next.  How are you planning to support the customer when they call and tell you "it doesn't work when I do *this*!"  Talk to your supervisor about getting an MSDN subscription to get access to all relevant Office versions.

Answer (score 0):

`o2007pia.msi` is not forward-compatible with Office 2010.  Use the Office 2010 PIA, which should be backward-compatible with Office 2007, so long as you don't use any Office 2010 specific features.

Comment: Thanks! I went back and looked at References, hadn't previously seen that both Office12 and Office14 versions of PIA were available. Switched out 14, switched in 12, everything is beautiful.